# Can I django filter a CharField by range?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can I filter the prices between 5 and 15 for all the products?

I have this model:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.CharField(max_length=150, default= 12)
```

I tried

```py
Products.objects.all().filter(price__range=(5, 15))
```

but I get no objects.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why are you using a CharField, especially if you want to filter it numerically? Why not an integerfield or decimalfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can Django filter a CharField by range?

Probably. A `__range` field lookup is pushed directly through the database as a `BETWEEN` query. And since strings are ordered (i.e. subject to collation), `BETWEEN` works for char fields.

> ... but I get no objects

Because `5` and `15` are converted to strings for the char field. And in every string collection I know `'5' > '15'` hence there cannot be any values within that range.

As suggested by @Daniel-Roseman if you want numeric comparison, use a proper [numeric field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) and the range will work as expected.

Comment: Changing to a numeric field solved all the problems.Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use Cast function and convert the result of price field to integer and then do a range filter

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Products.objects.annotate(price_as_int=Cast('price',IntegerField()).filter(price_as_int__range=(5,15))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this question on Google looking to actually implement a RangeFilter on a CharField, this is also possible but not by default. First create this class before your filter:

```
from django import forms
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters, fields

class CharRangeFilter(filters.RangeFilter):
    class CharRangeField(fields.RangeField):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(fields=(
                forms.CharField(),
                forms.CharField()
            ), *args, **kwargs)
        field_class = CharRangeField
```

And then use it in your filter, like this for example:

```
class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    my_char_field = CharRangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['my_char_field']
```

The reason creating your own `RangeField` class is because `RangeFilter` dynamically creates a `RangeField`, which by default uses two `DecimalField` objects, and the default can't be changed from the `RangeFilter` object because `RangeFilter` is only aware of `RangeField` via `field_class`.