# Django : Query for date range when date is stored as string

Tags: django, django-models

For some reasons I'm required to store date as string `2023-03-03` and I have a requirement to filter this data using date range.

Given starting date (say `2023-03-01`) and end date (`2023-03-04`) I have to find all the rows between the given dates.

Currently I'm using this query

```
Sample.objects.filter(date__range=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"])
```

which is giving results.

I'm not able to understand how it is working. I'm looking to see if this approach I'm following is right of if there's better approach to query this data.

Comment: take a look. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668718/16250404)  and also [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668703/16250404)

Comment: Because of comparing strings, checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836197/can-i-django-filter-a-charfield-by-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of one of the advantages of the ISO 8601 date format (which you are correctly using):

When you sort the dates alphabetically, the dates will be correctly ordered.

The django / postgres `__range` query can also compare alphabetically, so this works.

So when you *have* to use a text field for dates, you can totally put them into it in ISO 8601 format, and compare / order them as you wish, as long as you create an index on the column (`db_index=True`). It won’t be as efficient as normal postgres dates, and also date-specific postgres features need converting, so will be slower.